# How to assign value from listbox from datasource to a string

Tags: asp.net

I am stuck into a asp.net use case where a listbox(id:l1) is getting populated from a query which returns say 3 columns(name, id, value), now the id is assigned to l1.datavaluefield="id" , but i want to store the value of name in a string variable based on which ever item I click on the listbox. How do i do this please help

I have no idea at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does not really matter if the query returns 3 columns, or 10 columns.

The list box only has provisions for 2 columns. So, in most cases, you store the "value" as the database "ID" column, and then you have a column for display of the 2nd column.

To get "other" columns - ones not included in the listbox?

you as a genreal rule have to use the "ID" and re-pull (use anohter query) to get those other columns.

So, say we have a list box, it will display ID, and HotelName (2 columns). it really does not matter if you feed the listbox 5 or 10 columns, it will still only use + store + have the 2 columns.

So, lets setup a list box, and when you click on the given hotel, we will display other columns from that table on the web page.

So, this list box, and a bit more to display the other columns:

```
        <h4>Select Hotel</h4>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" Height="162px" Width="308px" >
        </asp:ListBox>

        <br />

        <h4>Hotel Informaton</h4>

        <div style="width: 303px; height: 185px;">
            <div style="text-align: right">
                HotelName: <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br />
                City:      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            Descripiton:
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="83px" Width="290px"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
```

And our code behind is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData
    End If
End Sub

Sub Loaddata()

    Dim strSQL As string =
        "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA
        ORDER BY HotelName"
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)

    ListBox1.DataSource = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    ListBox1.DataBind()

End Sub


Protected Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim PKID As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID")
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PKID

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)

    With rstData.Rows(0)
        txtHotel.Text = .Item("HotelName")
        txtCity.Text = .Item("City")
        txtDesc.Text = .Item("Description")
    End With


End Sub

Public Function MyrstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using mycon As New SqlConnection(GetConstr)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = mycon
            mycon.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function
```

And now we get/see this:

[image]

So, note how we are free to get/use/have ANY column from the database. However, since the listbox ONLY holds those two columns, then we have to hit the database again based on the LB selecting, pull the additional columns, and at that point we are free to use/have/enjoy use of all database columns, not just the ones used in the bl